# Расчет доставки

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api

подскажите,как реализовать такой расчет доставки на сайте?

как здесь https://gepur.com/help?way=delivery  или здесь https://mamsy.ru/siteinfo/delivery/

может они какое-то api используют?

Answer (score 1):

Такой расчет доставки реализуется с использованием API
Например

```
Для деловых линий - https://dev.dellin.ru/api/
Для Cdek - https://www.cdek.ru/clients/integrator.html
```

и т.д.

Comment: то есть чтобы вывести для 4 нужно делать запрос к каждой по отдельности?